# Insert multiple rows in MySQL and check for random string without long delay (~80 rows each minute)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert, cron

For a research project I am obtaining data from a local bus company's GPS system (through their API). I created a php cron job that runs every minute to obtain data like the vehicle, route ID, location, destination, etc. The data did not contain a unique "run number" for each bus route (a unique number so that I can track the progression of a single bus along its route), so I created my own that checks if the vehicle ID, destination, and relative time are similar, and assigns the unique "run ID" to it so that I can track the bus along its route. If no run ID exists, a random one is generated. (Any vehicle with the same "vid" and "pid" within 2 minutes of the last inserted row "timeadded" is on the same run, and this is important for my research)

Each time the cron runs (1 minute), approximately 80 rows are added into the database.

Initially the job would run quickly. However, with over 500,000 rows now, I've noticed the job can take upwards of 40 seconds. I believe it's because for each of the ~80 rows, it has to check the entire table ("vehicles") to see if the same run ID exists, essentially querying a large table and inserting a row 80 times. I want to get at least a week's worth of data (on day 4 now), at which point I can export the data, erase all rows, and start over. My question is: Is there any way I can refactor my PHP/SQL code to make the process run faster? It's been years since I've worked with SQL, so I'm sure there's a more ingenious way to insert all this data.

```
<?php
// Obtain data from XML
$xml = simplexml_load_file("url.xml");
foreach ($xml->vehicle as $vehicle) {
    $vid = $vehicle->vid;
    $tm = $vehicle->tmstmp;
    $dat = substr($vehicle->tmstmp, 0, 8);
    $tme = substr($vehicle->tmstmp, 9);
    $lat = $vehicle->lat;
    $lon = $vehicle->lon;
    $hdg = $vehicle->hdg;
    $pid = $vehicle->pid;
    $rt = $vehicle->rt;
    $des = $vehicle->des;
    $pdist = $vehicle->pdist;

     // Database connection and insert
    mysql_connect("redacted", "redacted", "redacted") or die(mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("redacted") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql_findsim = "SELECT vid, pid, timeadded, run, rt FROM vehicles WHERE vid=" . mysql_real_escape_string($vid). " AND pid=" . mysql_real_escape_string($pid). " AND rt=" . mysql_real_escape_string($rt). " AND timeadded > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE);";
    $handle = mysql_query($sql_findsim);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($handle);
    $runid = $row[3];
    if($runid !== null) {
        $run = $runid;
    } else {
        $run = substr(md5(rand()), 0, 30);
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO vehicles (vid, tmstmp, dat, tme, lat, lon, hdg, pid, rt, des, pdist, run) VALUES ($vid,'$tm','$dat','$tme','$lat','$lon',$hdg,$pid,'$rt','$des',$pdist,'$run')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

mysql_close();

}
```

?>

Thanks for any help with refactoring this code to get it to run more quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any indexes on the table? A compound index on (vid,pid,rt,timeadded) will make the query faster, avoiding a full table scan.

```
create index fastmagic on vehicles (vid,pid,rt,timeadded)
```

Alternatively, you could skip the select all together and just to the insert without assigning the "run" random value. This will keep your cron job at "constant time" since all you're doing is appending new data.

After you've got your week of data go back and write "second pass" code to step through each row (select * from vehicle order by timeadded). For each row, do your "select" similar to how you've already done it - then "update" the row you are processing now.

If you go with the alternate, you'll probably want an autoincrement "id" integer column to make row identification clearer (if you don't already have one).

Comment: Kevin, the index is perfect. Queries now running at 1-2 seconds, just ran the cron job manually and it completed in 2 seconds. Thanks for your help. Also need to do a second pass to assign different data to the points, and will test if that is a good solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that,

Create a table as vehicle_ids ( or some meaningful name ) these fields.

```
vid,  pid, run, rt
```

instead of checking in vehicles table for vid, you can check the above table for id, if not insert ( make vid as auto increment ).

Normalize your table and also index your vehicle table